# Changing the startupuri to a derived window class

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say in a WPF project I've built an abstract window class so I can add some base properties to every window I create derived from that:

```
// Abstract window, based on normal window
public abstract partial class abs_window : Window
{
    // example of added property to my abstract class
    protected int xxx = 25;

    public abs_window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}

// Another class dervied from my abstract window 
public partial class derivedWindow : abs_window
{
    void aa()
    {
        // Random method aa() to show access to the protected xxx int
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(xxx));
    }
}
```

So, this compiles fine, but my StartUpUri is pointing to the default MainWindow that I don't really want at all... I want it to point straight to a new instance of my doubly derived `derivedWindow` class? Is that possible?

I tried both
`StartupUri="abs_window.xaml"` and `StartupUri="derivedWindow.xaml">` but the first couldn't work since it's abstract and the 2nd doesn't work because there isn't an existing .xaml file

If I add a new "window" .xaml file it'll just be a normal window and not my derived type!?

Comment: Use the Startup event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-get-and-set-the-main-application-window

Comment: Looks perfect, thanks for that, always simple answers but sometimes there's just too much information online to know where to start.

Comment: Although I've created the App_Startup event, it's not being fired. Still not sure what to put in the StartupUri to get that startup event to fire.

Comment: Ah, never mind! I found that I just need to replace `StartupUri` with `Startup` and point it to `="App_Startup"` - thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering on behalf of Hans' comment unless he chooses to answer also:

First created a startup method in the default `App` class (`App.xaml.cs`) like Hans' link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-get-and-set-the-main-application-window)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        derivedWindow window = new derivedWindow();
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

But what that link didn't mention was to change the `App.xaml` file by replacing a `StartupUri` which seems to be always referencing an `.xaml` with a `Startup` method `StartupUri="MainWindow"` with `Startup="App_Startup"` which I found [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/working-with-app-xaml/)